# Unity tweak tool installation problems

Tags: software-installation

Whenever I am trying to install unity tweak tool through command line, this message shows up

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

How to rectify this ?

Comment: reboot the computer and try again.

Comment: I have done but the same problem persists...

Comment: You get this error when another program is using the admin privileges. Like when you start update manager or does anything with `sudo` in the terminal, the admin privileges will be locked to that process, so no other can use it. so just start one terminal and try to install unity tweak from there, without anything else running. Report back if it works now.

Comment: it is working now...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have not opened other programs that use dpkg like the Software Manager or the software updater and try again.